# Get the outlookItem type of an attachment in outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I am getting the attachments from an outlook mail. There are some traps aroudn this from c#, but most of them are solved by some ugly hacks. But there is one that I am not able to solve.

If I add an attachment as a file, the whole filename is saved including the file extenssion. So when I save the file to disc later it's saved correctly so I can only dblclick the file and it's opened in the correct application.

But if the attachement is added using the "Attach Item" -> "Add outlook Item", the mail/calender/contact is added without the file extenssion. So If I add a mail to my mail with this function then the .msg fileextension is not part of the filename and when trying to save it to disc it is recognized as an outlook mail.

But if I check in outlook I can see that the correct icon is added for this attachment, so outlook is able to know if it's a mail / contact / calenderitem so the information should be there somewhere.

Does anybody knows how to find out that it's a .msg that is in the attachment?

Comment: You can look for code that will read the first 256 bytes of a file and look for its MIME type.  Here is some code that could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547654/determine-the-file-type-using-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

When you pass an Outlook item to Attachments.Add, you add create an embedded message attachment (Attachment.Type = olEmbeddeditem) as opposed to the regular olByValue attachment.

BTW, the filename(Attachment.FileName) will always include the .msg extension. What are the cases when it is not there?