# Prevent an exe from being uploaded even after renaming its extention

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, exe

I am working on asp.net with **c#**.

There is a file upload control in my form. Everything is working fine.

The problem is that an `.exe` file can be uploaded by just renaming it. I would also like to restrict the size.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547654/determine-the-file-type-using-c-sharp) can help?

Answer (score 0):

best way in your case is check the first bytes of the file to determine what they are.

you should use [FindMimeFromData function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775107%28VS.85%29.aspx) to determines the MIME type from the data provided.

Have a look at [this](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) file signatures table

and at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature#answer-62007) SO answer that shows you how get mime type without using extension.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures) there is a table with List of file signatures

`exe` files have hex signature `4D 5A` (In ASCII representation, `0x5A4D` is `MZ`)

[image: signature of exe file]

from this point we can do this function

```
    public static bool IsExecutable(string filePath)
    {            
      var firstBytes = new byte[2];
      using (var fileStream = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open))
      {
          fileStream.Read(firstBytes, 0, 2);
      }
      return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(firstBytes) == "MZ";
    }
```