# Prevent upload file in Asp.net Web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a file upload functionality in my application which is for uploading a valid Image(JPG). However, a user is currently able to upload a `.exe` file by just changing the extension of the `exe` file to `.jpg`. Can we validate this file and give an error message to the user that it’s not a valid file? Anyone has implemented this check and can suggest?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25031190/prevent-an-exe-from-being-uploaded-even-after-renaming-its-extention and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature#answer-62007

Comment: Try with urlmon.dll in your application to validate the MIME type.