# Get file MIME type?

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, mime-types

I am writing advanced html server for my own purpose. Now i reached problem when specifying file type. Currently i determinate file type by extension

My function code:

```
Select Case extension.ToLower()
   Case ".avi"
      Return "video/x-msvideo"
   Case ".css"
      Return "text/css"
   Case ".doc"
      Return "application/msword"
   Case ".htm", ".html"
      Return "text/html"
      ...
   Case Else
      Return "application/octet-stream"
End Select
```

I use it like that:

```
Dim context as Net.HttpListenerContext
Dim file as String
context.Response.ContentType = getFileType(Path.GetExtension(file))
```

I accept answers also in C#

Edit:
My question is how i can simply get file type without registry and case?

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: This could be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547654/determine-the-file-type-using-c-sharp

Comment: And maybe this [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/y0211exb%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: @StefanoBafaro your link is useful but i don't want to pre-define mime types...

Comment: @BatuZet I know how to get file extension...

Comment: @user57601 There are 2 way: Using the registry or pre-define mime types. look at this: http://refactoringaspnet.blogspot.it/2008/11/how-to-get-content-type-mimetype-of.html

Comment: @StefanoBafaro okey, if there is no other way than registry or pre defined, i prefer more predefined... and thanks for the help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always use a dictionary and put the information in a setting file.

```
    Dim mimeTypeList As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

    mimeTypeList.Add(".avi", "video/x-msvideo")
    mimeTypeList.Add(".css", "text/css")
    mimeTypeList.Add(".avi", "application/msword")

    ' ...

    If mimeTypeList.Contains(extension.ToLower()) Then
        Return mimeTypeList(extension.ToLower())
    End If

    Return "application/octet-stream"
```

But I'm pretty sure IIS already has all of this built-in.

Comment: your answer is similar to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4465905/2425747) but yours don't have auto finding function. And i am using `System.Net.HttpListener`.

Comment: Ah! I tought you asked for an alternative to case. Not an alternative to get the mime type... The list could be stored once using global.asax There's this function http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx